# Is there a way to eliminate borders on a DataGridColumn in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I can't see a way to get rid of certain borders within a DataGrid.  I'd like to eliminate a side border on 2 of my columns so that they appear to look like a single column.

I'm trying to implement a "clear value" button on each of my DataGrid rows.  I was able to have a button show on a custom ItemRenderer from a separate ActionScript file, but I was unsure how to have the button click event propagate to the mxml file where the DataGrid is located.  It would be much easier for me to have an extra unresizable column with a 'clear' button.

So, to reiterate:  **Is there any way to change the border style or eliminate certain borders of a `DataGridColumn`?**

Comment: You need to skin the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hacky, but I found a solution to fit my needs.  I made a clear separator skin and used it as the `verticalLockedSeparatorSkin`, then locked the columns up until the separator.  This worked because I had no horizontal scrolling in my `DataGrid`.  It only allows, however, for the elimination of a single border between 2 columns (which is all I needed):

DataGrid mxml:

```
<mx:DataGrid lockedColumnCount="2" verticalLockedSeparatorSkin="ClearGridSeparatorSkin">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn />
        <mx:DataGridColumn />  <!-- this column is to the left of the clear separator -->
        <mx:DataGridColumn />  <!-- this column is on the right side of the separator -->
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Separator skin (as actionscript class):

```
package com.example.ClearSeparator
{
    import mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin;
    public class ClearGridSeparatorSkin extends ProgrammaticSkin
    {
        public function ClearGridSeparatorSkin()
        {
            this.alpha=0;
            this.width=1;
            super();
        }
    }
}
```